# Codeigniter: Paginate data without using table library

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Basically Im using Bootstrap themes with Codeigniter

Here is my controller code. tutors is the table from database.

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/bootstrap/index.php/frontpage/index';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('tutors')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 6;
    $config['num_links'] = 10;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['records'] = $this->db->get('tutors', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));

    $this->load->view('include/header');
    $this->load->view('frontpage', $data);
    $this->load->view('include/footer');
}
```

I want to customize the view as the followings

```
<div class="container" style="text-align: center;">

    <?php 
        $i=0;

        foreach($records as $row) : 
            if ($i%3==0) { ?>
                <div class="row"> 
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <h1><?php echo $row->title; ?></h1>
                        <h2><?php echo $row->id; ?></h2>
                    </div>
            <?php 
            } else { 
            ?>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h1><?php echo $row->title; ?></h1>
                    <h2><?php echo $row->id; ?></h2>
                </div>
                <?php 
                if ($i%3==2) {
                    echo "</div>"; 
                } 
            }

            $i++; 
        endforeach; 
    ?>  
</div>

<div class="container">
    <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
</div>
```

But it gets an error. How can I modify it?
Thanks guys.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: views/frontpage.php

Comment: oh, did I miss to declare variable $row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

foreach ($query->result() as $row)

instead of foreach($records as $row)